# Curve modifier not working, Can only deform along z axis

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am working with the curve modifier for the face of a character I'm making. I'd like to be able to curve the mouth to make facial expressions. But I can't get the sides of the mouth to come inwards, it just acts like the curve vertex has moved vertically. I can get the lips to move up and down, but not sideways.

this works (moving on z as expected):
[image: moves on z like it should]
this doesn't (moving on z, but should move on x):
[image: moves on z instead of x]

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thx.

**Update:**
Lets suppose I wanted to be able to make a face like the one made below. This is what i mean by I want the sides of the mouth to come inwards. By making the sides of the mouth closer to one another, with the curve. (I did not use the curve in this example)
[image]

Comment: How is your curve oriented, is it a 2D curve or 3D? Is it Rotated facing the carema or is its local XY pointing upwards? How is your object topology and vertex groups? Please edit your question and provide more details, possibly upload a **simplified** [blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Comment: it is a 2D curve

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2736" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2736/)

Comment: Why do you want to use a curve for that? Also, it is best to use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your .blend file.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what is worng with your curve specifically, but replacing it with a **Bezier Curve** instead of a NURBS Path seems to solve the issue.

Converting didn't seem to be enough

[image]

Comment: Thx. but this is not what i'm looking for. I updated the question to fit what i'm asking for more specifically. I am certain it is possible because i have managed to do it before.